# getting this is undefined Error at React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am always getting this is undefined error at react
although i dont know how to solve this

```
{this.state.persons.map(function (person) {
  return (
      <tr data-testid="article" key="article-index">
          <td data-testid="article-firstName" id="personID">{person.id}</td>
          <td data-testid="article-firstName">{person.firstName}</td>
          <td data-testid="article-lastName">{person.lastName}</td>
          <td data-testid="article-lastName">{person.age}</td>
          <td data-testid="article-email">{person.email}</td>
          <button className="small" onClick={this.updatePerson}>Search</button>
          <td><button className="btn btn-danger small">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
  )
})}
```

Here I add A Event Listener `onClick={this.updatePerson}`

and this is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      persons: this.props.persons
  }
  this.updatePerson = this.updatePerson.bind(this);
}
```

And Here is my update Function

```
updatePerson() {
  console.log("Updated Person");
}
```

But Every time iam running this its giving me a error

this is undefined

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
{this.state.persons.map((person) => {
    return (
        <tr data-testid="article" key="article-index">
            <td data-testid="article-firstName" id="personID">{person.id}</td>
            <td data-testid="article-firstName">{person.firstName}</td>
            <td data-testid="article-lastName">{person.lastName}</td>
            <td data-testid="article-lastName">{person.age}</td>
            <td data-testid="article-email">{person.email}</td>
            <button className="small" onClick={this.updatePerson}>Search</button>
            <td><button className="btn btn-danger small">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    )
})}
```

Comment: It's working nice. thanks for your contribution

Comment: It's because 'this' inside a function contains the function's scope, not the component's.